# Como listar os resultados de uma busca com regex num diretório?

Tags: regex, powershell

Tenho um diretório com alguns arquivos C#. Nestes arquivos há vários códigos SQL de consulta.

Preciso listar todos os comandos SELECT nestes arquivos utilizando PowerShell. 
Os comandos começam com `SELECT` e terminam com `;` e podem ter mais de uma linha, como o exemplo:

```cs
SQL = "SELECT t.a, t.b, t.c FROM uf_GetResultSet(4, 1, 0, 0, 'G', 0, 0, 0) t";
(...)
SQL = "SELECT t.a, t.b, t.c" + 
      "FROM uf_GetResultSet(4, 3, 0, 0, 'C', " + idSomeThing.ToString() + ", 0, 0) t";
```

O padrão regex `SELECT .+[\r\n]*.+";` me atende perfeitamente utilizando o Notepad++, mas não sei como adaptá-lo no PS.

Answer (score 2):

Eu cheguei ao seguinte comando:

```shell
PS> select-string -path *.cs -pattern "(?smi)(?<sql>SELECT .+?);" | foreach {$_.matches} | foreach {$_.groups['sql']} | select value
```

Mas ele retorna os SELECTs de apenas uma linha.

Answer (score 2):

Se você não precisar listar as linhas em que os selects se encontram, você pode usar o código abaixo:

```
$arquivos = Get-Content *.cs | Out-String
$selects = [Regex]::Matches($arquivos, "(?si)(SELECT.+?;)")
$selects | Select-Object -Expand Value
```

Como você quer buscar SELECTs que começam em uma linha e podem terminar em outra, o primeiro passo é transformar as várias linhas do Get-Content em uma só, com o cmdlet Out-String.

O segundo passo é usar a classe .NET System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex por meio do acelerador [Regex], já que ela é capaz de retornar todos os matches de uma string, ao contrário do operador -match.

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito bem o que deseja fazer (o porque dos foreachs), pois é so usar o select-string que teopricamente vai funcionar :
select-string -path *.cs -pattern "(?smi)(?SELECT .+?);"